# Generate All Unique Permutations of an Array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

In SAS if I have a string or an Array like the following,

```
array x[4] $1 ('A' 'B' 'C' 'D');
```

I need to generate all "Unique" permutations of the elements like the following,

```
[ABCD]
[ABC]
[BCD]
[ACD]
[ABD]
[AB]
[AC]
[AD]
[BC]
[BD]
[CD]
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

Is there a function in SAS for generating all possible combinations of the array?

Comment: I think this is combination instead of permutation.

Comment: `AB` and `BA` are different permutations but the same combination.

Comment: As asked this was asking for code.  Asking the way I edited is more acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. The only thing I was looking for is generating all possible "Unique" variations, so it does not matter what you call it combination or permutation both are ok for me.

Answer (score 3):

**Assumption**: I believe you are looking for `combinations` and not `permutations`, so the order does not matter, `BA` and `AB` are same thing.

Use `call allcomb` subroutine and `comb` function to find out the possible combinations.

Read more about `allcomb` and `comb` here

- http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0yx35py6pk47nn1vyrczffzrw25.htm

and here

- http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001009658.htm

In short -

- `call allcomb` subroutine gives the possible combinations out of `n` elements when `r` of them are taken and
- `comb` function gives you how many combinations it would be when out of `n` elements `r` of them are taken at a time.

---

```
data test(keep=my_string);
length my_string $50.;
  array a[4] $ ('A' 'B' 'C' 'D');

  n = dim(a);

   do k=1 to n;
         do j=1 to comb(n,k);
             call allcomb(j,k,of a[*]);
                 do i = 1 to k;
                    if i=1 then do; my_string="";counter=0;end;
                    counter=counter+1;
                    my_string=cat(compress(my_string),compress(a[i]));
                 if counter=k then output;

                 end;
           end;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @NEOmen . I will surely look into this. Seems like this should be able to generate what I want.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different take on this is to use `proc summary`.

Create a dummy dataset.  Assign each element of the array to a variable so we can feed it into `proc summary`:

```
data tmp;
  array arr[*] a b c d (1 1 1 1);
run;
```

Run `proc summary`.

```
proc summary data=tmp noprint missing;
  class a b c d;
  output out=combinations;
run;
```

You can also use the `ways` or `types` statements in `proc summary` to limit any combinations you may want.

Now the interesting side effect of doing this is that you get the `_type_` column in the output dataset as well.  In the example above the following values would be assigned:

```
D = 1
C = 2
B = 4
A = 8
```

So if the `_type_` value in the output dataset is 13, then we know that the row was generated by combining A, B and D (8 + 4 + 1).

Comment: +1 Very nice. I'm so used to using `nway` that I often forget about the class grouping. I don't think you need the `var`, `sum`, `dummy` or any of the options though, the default behaviour with just `class` and  `output out` should give the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I have never used a pro summary before. I will definitely try this.

Comment: @SRSwift Good points - I've updated the code based on your suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick script that will find the combinations of the individual characters within a string. This could be easily adapted to work with arrays if you prefer. Rather than using the combinational functions and call routines (`all*`, `lex*`, `ran*`) this approach creates the permutations by using the binary representation of integers up to `2**len`. I prefer this approach as I think it demonstrates what is happening, is more transparent and doesn't change the order of the array assignments.

```
data have;
    str = "123456"; output;
    str = "ABCD"; output;
run;
data want;
    set have;
    length comb $20.;
    len = length(str);
    /* Loop through all possible permutations */
    do _i = 0 to 2**len - 1;
        /* Store the current iteration number in binary */
        _bin = putn(_i, "binary" || put(len, best.) || ".");
        /* Initialise an empty output variable */
        comb = "";
        /* Loop through each value in the input string */
        do _k = 1 to len;
            /* Check if the kth digit of the binary representation is 1 */
            /* And if so add the kth input character to the output */
            if substr(_bin, _k, 1) = "1" then 
                comb = cats(comb,  substr(str, _k, 1));
        end;
        output;
    end;
    /* Clean up temporary variables, commented so you can see what's happening */
/*  drop _:; */
run;
```

---

If you *do* want permutations then a [similar approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations) is possible using factoradic representations of the numbers. But, I would recommend that you use a combinational function instead as the conversions would be much more involved. It's probably quite a nice coding exercise for learning though.

---

It would be great if SAS had a function for reducing strings by boolean patterns, but it probably wouldn't get much use.

```
bsubstr("ABCD", "1010") --> "AC"
bsubstr("ABCD", "1110") --> "ABC"
bsubstr("ABCD", "0001") --> "D"
```

Comment: Thanks @SRSwift. This is the most different way of doing it. No one has even suggested this to me, but it makes sense and looks interesting, I will try it out too.

Answer (score 0):

SAS has in-built functions to calculate combinations & permutations, `allcomb` and `allperm`.

SAS Documentation for ALLCOMB function : http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003112305.htm

Comment: Thank Chris, I had a look at the allcomb function but was not able to generate unique variations of the array elements.