# Creating Combinations in SAS

Tags: sas

Helloo..So am trying to derive combinations of 3 variables from 378 variables on SAS. Any help?

```
I have tried the below code but no luck:

Proc plan;
Factors Block=8930376 ordered
Variable=2 of 378 comb;

Ods output Plan=Comb_MEV;
Quit;
```

Comment: What is your desired result here? A data set?

Comment: Yes a data set with all 8930376 combinations (ex. 1,2,3   1,2,4  1,2,5....etc)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340151/generate-all-unique-permutations-of-an-array-in-sas

Comment: So, when you have 1, 2, 3. You do not want 3, 2, 1 correct?

Answer (score 4):

This is a modified version of the example for ALLCOMBI

```
data comb;
   array i[3];
   n=378;
   k=3;
   i[1]=0;
   ncomb=comb(n,k);    /* The one extra call goes back */
   do j=1 to ncomb+1;  /* to the first combination. */
      call allcombi(n, k, of i[*]);
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc print data=comb(obs=40);
   run;
```